# What does integrability of a function with respect to a (Levy) measure tell us about the measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

We often use Levy measures $\Pi$ as the jump distributions for a Compound Poisson distribution. I think the condition $\Pi(\{0\})=0$ tells us that we should not have jumps of size 0 (at least with probability 0).

But what does the condition $\int 1 \wedge x^2 \ \Pi(dx)< \infty$ tell us about the Levy measure and/or the jumps?

I more used to thinking about "if $f$ has to be intgrable with respect to this measure $\mu$, then $f$ cannot jump to much, must behave nicely around 0, etc.", but I am not used to the reverse (as in this case) "if $\mu$ integrates this function $f$, then $\mu$ has to..."

Can anyone help? How does one relate integrability to the **measure**? I have tried searching the archives for a similar question but could not find one.